# Is any Tomorrowland Orchestra music available on CD?

Tags: recording, cd

I have become a big fan of the Tomorrowland Orchestra after hearing them performing [Opus from Eric Prydz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVy126sGK5A&t=2188s). I have searched for any CDs (or other high quality recordings) of their music, but what seemed to be an easy task turned into impossible. I thought when you orchestrate so many songs then the least you can do is to record all this properly for future generations to enjoy. Is there really nothing besides youtube? Or am I simply missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tomorrowland](https://www.tomorrowland.com/global/) Orchestra is actually The [Metropole Orkest](https://www.mo.nl/en/), an orchestra for hire based in the Netherlands. Wikipedia's entry for them includes a [selected discography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropole_Orkest#Discography).

The Metropole Orkest seems not to release commercial recordings under its own name, and the Tomorrowland Festival has only [one recording](https://store.tomorrowland.com/products/cd-united-through-music-black) I've found, of their 2020 festival.
I've also not found a commercial recording of Eric Prydz's "Opus" with orchestra, but there is at least [one other YouTube recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXmSEW6fqPU) made by the Helsinki Philharmonic Orchestra, but in a different arrangement than the Tomorrowland version.